# Trimble Geoexplorer XT 6000 - Change Language

Tags: internationalization, trimble, geoexplorer

Does anyone know if it possible and if so how to change the language on the Trimble Geoexplorer XT 6000?

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible (I've had Geo6000 and Geo7 units in various languages) but from memory, the language is set during first OS start. I tried doing a factory reset as described in [this Support Note](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Ftrl.trimble.com%2Fdocushare%2Fdsweb%2FGet%2FDocument-529490%2FSN17195_GeoExplorer6000Series_ResettingTheHandheld_ENG.pdf&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNH4fbMqJqHVdLbKrSh8Rxjx6khGCA),  that doesn't change the language, I believe you need to do a full OS install, but I can't find the files to do a full OS install.  Trimble only generally supplies the files needed to do an update from one OS version to the next.

I know that full OS install packages were available on request from the Trimble Support guys but if you don't have a Support contract that isn't going to help.  I'll scratch around a bit, see if I can find a link.